# will require( tx.origin == msg.sender ) block my function in the future (Ethereum upgrades)?

Tags: security

I am trying to use require( tx.origin == msg.sender ) in very specific functions such as transferOwnership and selfdestruct functions. This aims to make sure that the caller of this function is doing it without any contract in between (trying to prevent a not-seen-yet attack). However, I have read in some forums this might prevent my functions to be interacted with in the future due to changes planned ahead in the Ethereum protocol. How true is this? Or is just onlyOwner enough?

Comment: I recommend against doing something 'just in case' of some unknown future attack. Without knowing the exact code it hard to recommend something but probably onlyOwner is enough. I have yet to see code that requires more than onlyOwner. 

The story goes that after a bug involving tx.origin they realized that it wasn't a good abstraction. It is not recommend to rely on it, but you can use it without issues. It is unlikely to change its behavior in the near future, but they may change it after eth2.0.

Comment: you are right. Honestly, it doesn't really add any extra security. Only adds the risk of being unusable in later upgrades. Thank you.